# Javascript/laravel - Function in onclick is not found

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have the following Javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    setHeightByAttr('Sum');
} 
); 

function setAllSameHeight()
{
    var t = document.getElementById("myTable");
    for(var i=0; i<t.rows.length; i++){
        t.rows[i].style.height = "30px"; 
    }

}

function setHeightByAttr(attr)
{
    //find the index of the attribute and save it in a variable called index



    setTimeout(function() {
        var index = null;
        var t = document.getElementById("myTable");
        for(var i = 0; i < t.rows[0].cells.length; i++){
            if(t.rows[0].cells[i].innerText == attr+"\n"){
                index = i;
                break
            }
        }
        t.rows[1].style.height = "30px";
        for(var i=2; i < t.rows.length; i++) {
            var sumi = t.rows[i].cells[index].innerHTML;
            var sumiminus1 = t.rows[i-1].cells[index].innerHTML;
            t.rows[i].style.height = 30+30*(Math.abs(sumi-sumiminus1)).toString()+"px";

        }   
    }, 5);
}
```

And the following view in Laravel:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h5>The Ranklist is last updated at {{$update}}</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <table id="myTable" class="table table-condensed tablesorter">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="rank">R</th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs flag" onclick= "setAllSameHeight()">Flag</th>
                        <th onclick="setAllSameHeight()">Name</th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs sortInitialOrder-desc" onclick= "setHeightByAttr('MC')">MC</th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs sortInitialOrder-desc" onclick= "setHeightByAttr('TC')">TC</th>
                        <th class="sortInitialOrder-desc" onclick="setHeightByAttr('SPE')">SPE</th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs sortInitialOrder-desc" onclick= "setHeightByAttr('HW')">HW</th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs sortInitialOrder-desc" onclick= "setHeightByAttr('Bs')">Bs</th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs sortInitialOrder-desc" onclick= "setHeightByAttr('KS')">KS</th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs sortInitialOrder-desc" onclick= "setHeightByAttr('Ac')">Ac</th>
                        <th class="sortInitialOrder-desc" onclick="setHeightByAttr('DIL')">DIL</th>
                        <th class="sortInitialOrder-desc" onclick="setHeightByAttr('Sum')">Sum</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The website does not behave as it should. What happens is this:

1. The rows are sorted accorded to the selected column attribute.
2. The height of the rows remain sorted by `'Sum'` as they are when the page is opened.

Why is this? It's as if the argument provided to `setHeightByAttr` in the laravel blade file is ignored and the function runs with `'Sum'` instead, if at all.

There must be something about how the js file is executed that I don't understand.

EDIT:

An excerpt from the javascript console shows that there is an error when calling the `setHeightByAttr` function. The function isn't found. Why not?

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: setHeightByAttr is not defined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.onclick (app.lzr.im/:1)
```

EDIT 2:

Here's the generated HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="nfnpuH42cZDLQD8TbCQkyK8z1lFGKiQqJC6X34DT">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Home
 - CS3226 RankList 2020</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->    
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <meta name="csrf-token" content="nfnpuH42cZDLQD8TbCQkyK8z1lFGKiQqJC6X34DT">


  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="/css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/css/flag-icon.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans%7cRaleway" rel="stylesheet"> -->
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      </div>
  <!-- Static navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">CS3233 Ranklist 2020</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li id="home" class="active"}}><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li id="history" }}><a href="/history">History</a></li>
          <li id="help" }}><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
                                            </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    <li  ><a href="https://app.lzr.im/login">Login</a></li>
          <li  ><a href="https://app.lzr.im/register">Register</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

    <div class="loader" style="margin:0 auto;"></div>
  <div id="tableLoaded"></div>


  <footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-right">© 2017 M. Ashmawi, C. G. Lim, Z. Lin, K. Xiao, S. F. Zarrinkoub & H. Zhao. <a href="https://github.com/cs3226-2017-3c" target="_blank"><img width="12" alt="GitHub" src="/img/GitHub-Mark-32px.png"></a></p>
      </div>
  </footer>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $('div.alert').not('.alert-important').delay(3000).fadeOut(350);
  </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/loader.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.28.5/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you able to post generated HTML?

Comment: Where do you include your js file? I cant see.

Comment: I don't know how it works in laravel, but I don't need to for ´setAllSameHeight´, which is successfully called in the HTML and is in the same JS file.

Comment: The file seems to be not included, or is it loader.js ?

Comment: you probably have an error in your template because `<li id="history" }}>` (and some others) that you have in your generated HTML is wrong...

Comment: How could possibly one function in `hightlights.js` work but not the other? As I said, `setAllSameHeight` works fine, but not `setHeightByAttr`. Doesn't make sense to say that the file is not included.

Comment: If your code have a name="setAllSameHeight"  the same with your fuction name .it will make the error!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why this happens, but if it help I found a workaround for this:

```
window.functionName =function(){
 //code and stuff
}
```